# Iframe overlapping position fixed div in IE 10 or more

Tags: html, css

```css
.test1{background:red;width:100%;height:50px;position:fixed;}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
test Pdf
</div>

<embed src="https://a.uguu.se/YudvfJROqhxH.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px">


<iframe src="https://a.uguu.se/YudvfJROqhxH.pdf" width="100%" height="600px">
This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf">Download PDF</a>
</iframe>
```

In IE 10 or more PDF overlapping menu. 
I tried lot of css including z-index but noting working.